# GCP: How to grant a role to a service account on a Firestore collection?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, service-accounts, google-iam

We can share a BigQuery dataset with a service account, we can add a service account as a member to a specific bucket by assigning to it a specific role....using graphic interface.

What about Firestore? Can we share a specific collection with a service account?? I couldn't find any such option in the web interface..

**Remark:** I don't have permission to grant global permissions to service account, but I have permission to add members to a resource and grant them roles over that specific resouce.

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to assign permissions to service accounts at that level of granularity in Firestore using [IAM for Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam).  A service account either has access to every document with the stated privilege, or nothing.

This runs in contrast with per-user access to Firestore via web and mobile clients authenticating with [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).  In that case, it's possible to assign per-user permissions using [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview).  It's worth nothing that accessing Firestore with a service account completely bypasses all rules established through Firebase.